# Automatically kill a script and restart it

Tags: python-3.x, bash, unix

I wrote a small script to run a program on gpu that consumes a lot of memory with tensorflow. The only reliable way to free up memory in gpu is to kill the whole script and then restart it. I am very new to bash and wonder if there is a way that I can kill the script and automatically restart it with bash. I want the kill process to be such that when a counter inside my script reached from 0 to 50, then the script got killed and memory got released. And then the script will start again automatically.

Comment: What distribution are you running? Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: One possibility might be to write a script that (a) starts your process, (b) records its PID, (c) starts a counter, (d) kills your job by PID if the counter is critical, all wrapped inside an infinite while true loop. For instance, the counter could be a sleep(3600) or it can also check the memory (ps -p <PID> -o %mem) followed by a sleep. Then (d) can kill if the memory is critical.